# How to send an embed message to a different channel in interactions?

Tags: discord, discord.js

How to send a separate embed message to a channel different from where the slash command was executed? My current code is the following block.

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits, EmbedBuilder, Guild } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('arrest')
        .setDescription('puts the member to jail')
    .addUserOption(option =>
      option
      .setName('target')
      .setDescription('The member to arrest')
      .setRequired(true))
    .addStringOption(option =>
            option
                .setName('reason')
                .setDescription('The reason for arrest'))
    .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.ModerateMembers),
    async execute(interaction) {
    const messageEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle('ARRESTED!')
      .setDescription(`***${interaction.options.getUser('target').tag}*** *broke a leg. Oops.*`)
      .setColor(0xBD7A21)
      .setImage('https://eca.astrookai.repl.co/media/arrest.gif')
      
    await interaction.reply({embeds: [ messageEmbed ]});
    },
};
```

Sending a separate embed object to a different channel is intended for channel logging for moderation actions in the server and I would like to know how to achieve this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<channel>.send()` for this. In which `<channel>` is your channel object. You can get the channel in a multiple of different ways but this is probably the easiest:

```
logChannel = <interaction>.guild.channels.fetch(SNOWFLAKE_ID)
```

Then, you can send your embed to the logchannel like so:

```
logChannel.send({ embeds: [YOUR_EMBED] });
```

To account for every command, the easiest way is to do this in your `interactionCreate` event

If you need more context, you can check out [this example](https://github.com/UndefinedToast/BobTheBot/blob/main/events/messageDelete.js) which "logs" an embed to the logChannel.

Comment: Make sure to `await` `GuildChannelManager.fetch()` or resolve it with `.then()`, for the function returns a promise